# Difference between random forest implementation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, data-science, h2o

Is there a performance difference between the implementation of Random Forest in H2O and standard Random Forest library?

Has anybody performed or done some analysis for these two implementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an open benchmark you can start with.

https://github.com/szilard/benchm-ml

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are looking for this: http://www.wise.io/tech/benchmarking-random-forest-part-1

Comment: Note this benchmark is about four years old and out of date, even though the date on the post strangely says 2017.  (Look at the 2015 date on the comment at the bottom.)  Also note the author, Erin, is now at H2O (full disclosure: I am too).

Comment: Well, at least this article can be a beginning. And I agree, that H2O could be better.

Comment: As the author of the wise.io benchmarking article, yes, it's very out of date.  The **randomForest** R code has changed very little since then, but both the H2O and sklearn RF implementations have improved a great deal in the past 4 years.

Comment: @AndreyLukyanenko If you have specific suggestions on how the H2O RF implementation can be better, please send your ideas to our mailing list (or even better, make a pull request): https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/h2ostream

Comment: @Erin LeDell I meant that I think that H2O is better that RF implementation (could in this case = not sure, but think so). Sorry for misunderstanding.